# LINQ query on a list of Object[] arrays

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Object arrays (List) That I am going to pass into a DLL function to apply PDF controls. The first index of each object is supposed to identify what the control will be. I was wondering if there is some way to query my list of objects to get a count of each of the identifying objects and cast it to an int? Here is a example of what i am trying to do ...

```
        List<Object[]> controlsList = new List<Object[]>();

        //Textfield = 1
        //Checkbox = 2
        Object[] control1 = new Object[] { 1, 1, 1, 75, 75, "txtField1", 1, 8, 10};
        Object[] control2 = new Object[] { 1, 1, 1, 144, 144, "txtField2", 1, 10, 15};
        Object[] control3 = new Object[] { 2, 1, 1, 50, 50, "checkYESNOy", 1, "Yes", "grpYesNo"};
        Object[] control4 = new Object[] { 2, 1, 1, 50, 50, "checkYESNOn", 1, "No", "grpYesNo" };
        Object[] control5 = new Object[] { 2, 1, 1, 50, 50, "checkDirectionN", 1, "North", "grpDirection" };
        Object[] control6 = new Object[] { 2, 1, 1, 50, 50, "checkDirectionS", 1, "South", "grpDirection" };
        Object[] control7 = new Object[] { 2, 1, 1, 50, 50, "checkDirectionW", 1, "West", "grpDirection" };
        Object[] control8 = new Object[] { 2, 1, 1, 50, 50, "checkDirectionE", 1, "East", "grpDirection" };


        controlsList.Add(control1);
        controlsList.Add(control2);
        controlsList.Add(control3);
        controlsList.Add(control4);
        controlsList.Add(control5);
        controlsList.Add(control6);
        controlsList.Add(control7);
        controlsList.Add(control8);

        //Some LINQ code to get back a count of all the textfields(1) and all the checkboxes(2)
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that you should define consts to get rid of your magic numbers (1, 2).  ... new Object[] { textBoxId, 1, 1, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int textBoxCount = controlsList.Count(o => (int)o[0] == 1);
int checkBoxCount = controlsList.Count(o => (int)o[0] == 2);
```

Comment: after playing around some more this morning, i found that your solution works even if the controls aren't entered in order. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
// group by first item of each object[]
var groups = controlsList.GroupBy(x => x[0]);

foreach( var g in groups ){
    var count = g.Count();
}
```

or

```
var groups = controlsList.GroupBy(x => x[0]).ToList();

var txtCount = groups[0].Count();
var chkCount = groups[1].Count();
```

Comment: wow thank you! Now I have one more question. How would I go about sorting the List by the first index? Could I use the same List variable or would I have to store it in a new List of Objects?

Comment: var groups = controlsList.GroupBy(x => x[0]).OrderBy(x => (int)x.Key);

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `GroupBy` followed by a `Count`:

```
var query = controlsList.GroupBy(arr => (int)arr[0])
                        .Select(g => new { Id = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

Now `query` will contain a list of objects with each identifier and a corresponding count.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob at linq, but maybe this will help you ...

```
        var c1 = from t in controlsList
                 where t[0].ToString() == "1"
                 select t;

        Console.WriteLine("text count = " + c1.Count());

        var c2 = from t in controlsList
                 where t[0].ToString() == "2"
                 select t;

        Console.WriteLine("check count = " + c2.Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Dictionary<object, int> controls = controlsList.GroupBy(x => x[0]).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
int textBoxCount = controls[1];
int checkBoxCount = controls[2];
```